# how to check if the value is in list of dict

Tags: python

I worked in the students' data file, and I see the best structure is like the example below -correct me if I wrong- which is a list of a collection of dictionaries, and the last key has a list of dictionaries.

> data = [
> {'student_name': 'Khaled ', 'student_id': '19190', 'student_major': 'CS', 'course': [{'course_code': 'PE101', 'course_name': 'Physical Education', 'course_credit': '1', 'course_grade': 'D+'}, {'course_code': 'MATH101', 'course_name': 'Calculus I', 'course_credit': '4', 'course_grade': 'D'}, {'course_code': 'PHYS101', 'course_name': 'Physics I', 'course_credit': '4', 'course_grade': 'F'}, {'course_code': 'CHEM101', 'course_name': 'Chemistry I', 'course_credit': '4', 'course_grade': 'A+\n'}]}, {'student_name': 'Rashed', 'student_id': '18730', 'student_major': 'MIS', 'course': [{'course_code': 'PHYS101', 'course_name': 'Physics I', 'course_credit': '4', 'course_grade': 'D+\n'}]}
> ]

I hope it's readable.

My question is why this code doesn't check if the id I entered correctly?

```
    ID = int(input("Enter you Id : "))

    for student in data: 
        if ID in student: 
            print("the ID is there")
            
        else:
            print("nothing")
```

Thanks in the future. If you suggest any modification of the file, let me know. I just want a full control for each element because my program has many other features

Comment: Doing `x in dict` is checking if `x` is a ***key*** in the dict. You're looking for a ***value***

Comment: Also note the `else` should be indented at the level of the `for` and not the `if`. You know there is no such ID only after iterating ***the whole*** dict. Right now you will get alot of `nothing`s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why this code doesn't check if the id I entered
> correctly?

That's because

```
if ID in student:
```

checks if `ID` exists as a *key* and you need to check the *value*.

Use

```
if student['student_id'] == ID:
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the `in` operator checks for a direct value in the list or checks if `key` exists in dict, i.e,

> 123 in [123, 'xyz']

or

> 'key' in {'key': 'value'}

would evaluate to True.

---

In your case, you want to check for a value in a dict, but code would check for `key` in a dict.

You could modify your code to check for the value in dict, like below

```py
ID = input("Enter you Id : ")

for student in data:
    if ID == student['student_id']: 
        print("the ID is there")
    else:
        print("nothing")
```

Here, check the `if` condition.

I am checking for value against each student's `student_id`. Also, check that I have removed `int` from `input` as `'123'` is not equals to `123` (quotes).